Why is it, after upgrading to Windows 11, the turtle icon is always on for VirtualBox guest VM?
I noticed this symptom after upgrading from Windows 10 to Windows 11, not sure whether related though.
I have ensured that:

CPU virtualization feature is enabled.
Hypver-V is disabled.
VirtualBox Extension Pack is installed.

However, the option "Enable VT-x/AMD-V" in the VM's Settings is grayed out. So, I enable it by a workaround of calling command VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "vm.name" --nested-hw-virt on. I am not sure whether this workaround works in this situation, because if uncheck the option, it still appears as grayed out as before.
And, I have also checked "Enable PAE/NX" and "Enable Nested Paging" in the VM's Settings.
Nevertheless, the turtle icon still shows up when running guest VMs. Also, the Guest VM often encounters memory access error while the turtle shows big slowness, see the below screenshot.
I have confirmed that another system service, not Hyper-V, is occupying the hardware virtualization feature of Windows. So, I wonder whether there is any workaround to avoid the above error and keep using the VM for functional test purposes.
Guest VM Error while Turtle Showing Slowness:


"still appears as grayed out as before." - This means it's disabled. If Enable VT-x/AMD-V cannot be enabled within the VM settings it means some other software is using the hardware virtualization. There are countless answers (multiple answers I submitted) on this subject which state this fact.

I suspect this is a duplicate of this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1006788/virtualbox-is-very-slow-in-windows-10/1613983#1613983

This question is similar to: VirtualBox is very slow in Windows 10. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Following this link, we checked the "Turn Windows Features On or Off" and disabled some services so that all the listed services are disabled.
We also enabled "PAE/NX", "Nested VT-x/ADM-V", and "Nested Paging" in the VM's Settings.
As a result, the turtle icon disappears, and we noticed significant speed up on the virtual machine boot.
However, the instability issue still exists on the specific guest operating system of RHEL9. We will post another question for it.

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: Accept Your Own Answers.
